# chi squared in scipy different from results in SPSS

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, spss, chi-squared

I'm trying to automate chi squared calculations. I'm using `scipy.stats.pearsonr`. However, that's giving me different answers than SPSS is. Like, factor of 10 difference. (.07 --> .8)

I'm pretty sure that the data is the same in both cases because I'm printing out the crosstab in both cases (using pandas.crosstab) and the numbers are identical.

```
d1 = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

d2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1]

print scipy.stats.stats.pearsonr(d1,d2)
```

gives:

```
 (-0.065191159985573108, 0.61172152831874682)
```

(the 1st is the coefficient, the 2nd is the p value)

However SPSS says that the Pearson Chi-Square is .057.

Is there something I should check other than the crosstab?

Comment: Could you also show the corresponding SPSS code?

Comment: Someone else made the SPSS, so I only have access to the output easily...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently you are computing the chi-squared statistic and p-value for the contingency table (i.e. "cross tab") of the data.  The scipy function `pearsonr` is not the correct function to use for this.  To do the calculation with scipy, you'll need to form the contingency table and then use [`scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html).

There are several ways you could convert `d1` and `d2` into a contingency table.  Here I'll use the Pandas function [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html).  Then I'll use `chi2_contingency` for the chi-squared test.

First, here is your data.  I have them in numpy arrays, but this is not necessary:

```
In [49]: d1
Out[49]: 
array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])

In [50]: d2
Out[50]: 
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1])
```

Use pandas to form the contingency table:

```
In [51]: import pandas as pd

In [52]: table = pd.crosstab(d1, d2)

In [53]: table
Out[53]: 
col_0   0   1  2
row_0           
0       5   7  4
1      10  34  3
```

Then use `chi2_contingency` for the chi-squared test:

```
In [54]: from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

In [55]: chi2, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(table.values)

In [56]: p
Out[56]: 0.057230732412525138
```

The p value matches the value computed by SPSS.

---

*Update*: In SciPy 1.7.0 (targeted for mid-2021), you'll be able to create the contingency table with `scipy.stats.contingency.crosstab`:

```
In [33]: from scipy.stats.contingency import crosstab  # Will be in SciPy 1.7.0 
In [34]: d1                                                                                                 
Out[34]: 
array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])

In [35]: d2                                                                                              
Out[35]: 
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1])

In [36]: (vals1, vals2), table = crosstab(d1, d2)                                                                          

In [37]: vals1                                                                                                      
Out[37]: array([0, 1])

In [38]: vals2                                                                                              
Out[38]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [39]: table                                                                                           
Out[39]: 
array([[ 5,  7,  4],
       [10, 34,  3]])
```